# Как реализовать динамическое редактирование таблиц?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как быть. Создаю таблицы, при клике на `td` в ячейке появляется текстовое поле, куда записываются данные с ячейки. Как мне перезаписать данные на новые и вставить их в ячейку? Как при нескольких нажатий на td не добавлять больше поля?

```
var table_id=0;
    function new_table() {
    var countTr = $("#tr").val();
    var countTd = $("#td").val();
    table_id++;
    $('#r').append("<table border ='1' id='t"+table_id+"'></table>");
    for (var i = 1; i <= countTr; i++) {
    $('#container #t'+table_id).append("<tr></tr>");
    for (var n = 1; n <= countTd; n++) {
     $('#container #t'+table_id+' tr:last').append("<td>" + i + "." + n + "</td>");
            }

        }
        $("table").draggable({ containment: 'parent' });

        $("table").resizable();

        $("table td").click(function () {
   $(this).html('<input type="text" size="4" value="' + $(this).html() + '" />');
  });
    };
```

Пример https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/LLen1fpa/19/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну кажется проще всего создавать таблицу, сразу заполненную текстовыми полями, и ничего не создавать при клике. Так можно будет перемещаться по таблице без мыши — тажатием tab. Кроме того это гарантированно работает, даже при отключенном js. Зачем вам такое поведение?

По теме вопроса — ну просто сохраните куда-нибудь, создавали вы уже там инпут или нет. Например в `data`:

```
$("table td").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).data('input')) {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" size="4" value="' 
                     + $(this).html() + '" />');
        $(this).data('input', true);
    }
});
```